# How to overried the selected classes in menuItem in material ui REACTjs?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, menuitem, styling

hello i am having a problem I can't overried the classe that shows the right styling when a menuItem is selected : 
here is my code :

```
       <MenuItem component={Link} to="/Acceuil" 
        className={{root:classes.menuItem ,selected:classes.selected}} 
           selected={pathname === "/Acceuil"} >
              <ListItemIcon>
                  <Icon className={classes.icon} >
                      insert_drive_file
                   </Icon>
               </ListItemIcon>
            Gestion Commandes
        </MenuItem>
```

and this is the classes const :

```
      Const classes = theme => ({
       menuItem: {
         fontStyle:'bold',
         backgroundColor: 'white',
         width: '88%',
      '&:active':{
        borderLeft: '4px solid #51bcda',
        backgroundColor: "-webkit-box-shadow: 6px 4px 53px -7px 
        rgba(0,0,0,0.75), -moz-box-shadow: 6px 4px 53px -7px 
        rgba(0,0,0,0.75),   box-shadow: 6px 4px 53px -7px 
        rgba(0,0,0,0.75),",
        },
       selected:{
       backgroundColor:'red !important' 
       } 
       });
```

thanks for helping me ^^

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To understand how to style this with the appropriate specificity, you need to look at the [`ListItem` source code](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/ListItem/ListItem.js) (`MenuItem` delegates most of its styling to `ListItem`).

Here are the relevant portions of the `ListItem` styling for the `selected` state:

```
export const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    '&$selected, &$selected:hover, &$selected:focus': {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.action.selected,
    },
  },
  /* Styles applied to the root element if `selected={true}`. */
  selected: {},
});
```

Below I've included an example of overriding the styling for the selected MenuItem along with a working [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/k096no1qkv) based on the [Selected menus demo](https://material-ui.com/demos/menus/#selected-menus).

```
const styles = theme => ({
  menuItemRoot: {
    "&$menuItemSelected, &$menuItemSelected:focus, &$menuItemSelected:hover": {
      backgroundColor: "red"
    }
  },
  menuItemSelected: {}
});
...
            <MenuItem
              classes={{
                root: classes.menuItemRoot,
                selected: classes.menuItemSelected
              }}
...
```

[image: Edit Menu selected styling]

Here's a similar question/answer for a different Material-UI component: [Styling BottomNavigation in React.js Material-UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54375096/styling-bottomnavigation-in-react-js-material-ui/54375949#54375949)