# Pass className from Parent to child and call css property issue - material ui react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a parent component as below

**Parent**

```
  loginForm: {
    margin: 0,
    '& $buttonContainer': {
      position: 'relative',
      marginTop: '195px',
    },
  },

       <div className={classes.login}>
          <LoginForm className={classes.loginForm} />
        </div>
```

My button container is position fixed in the child however I want to override from the parent

**Child:**

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    margin: '24px 16px',
  },
  mb1: {
    marginBottom: '13px',
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    position: 'fixed',
    bottom: theme.spacing(2),
    left: theme.spacing(2),
    right: theme.spacing(2),
  },
}));

  <form
      className={`${classes.root} ${props.className ? props.className : ''}`}
      <div className={classes.buttonContainer}>
        <Button
          fullWidth
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          size="large"
          type="submit"
          disabled={isEmptyValues(values.phone)}
        >
          {t('login_page.login_submit_get_code')}
        </Button>
      </div>
</form>
```

**Want to apply position relative on the buttonContainer however it doesn't work**

My question is this selector correct?

```
'& $buttonContainer': {
      position: 'relative',
      marginTop: '195px',
    },
```

Update:

[image]

Comment: What is the issue you are having on this?

Comment: You should create a minimal reproducible example (preferably on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/))

Comment: Did you inspect the classes for child component, what it is showing?

Comment: @Rohitha my question is there a way to access    <div className={classes.buttonContainer}> from parent

Comment: @hgb123 will add it in

Comment: Just want to understand while inspecting, do you see loginForm class?

Comment: @Rohitha yes have updated a screenshot of child component

Answer (score 1):

`$ruleName` refers to a rule with that name in the **same style sheet** (i.e. within the same `makeStyles` call). It won't match a rule that happens to have the same name in a different `makeStyles` call (the generated class names will be different).

There are a number of different ways to approach this problem. Below is one approach that keeps largely the same structure as your original code and passes the `buttonContainer` class in a separate, optional prop.

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import clsx from "clsx";

const useParentStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  loginForm: {
    margin: 0,
    "& $buttonContainer": {
      position: "relative",
      marginTop: "195px"
    }
  },
  buttonContainer: {}
}));
const LoginFormParent = () => {
  const classes = useParentStyles();
  return (
    <LoginForm
      className={classes.loginForm}
      buttonContainerClassName={classes.buttonContainer}
    />
  );
};

const useChildStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    margin: "24px 16px"
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    position: "fixed",
    bottom: theme.spacing(2),
    left: theme.spacing(2),
    right: theme.spacing(2)
  }
}));

const LoginForm = (props) => {
  const classes = useChildStyles();
  return (
    <form className={clsx(classes.root, props.className)}>
      <div
        className={clsx(
          classes.buttonContainer,
          props.buttonContainerClassName
        )}
      >
        <Button
          fullWidth
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          size="large"
          type="submit"
        >
          Login
        </Button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};
export default function App() {
  return <LoginFormParent />;
}
```

[image: Edit Style child from parent]

Related answers:

- [How do you change a style of a child when hovering over a parent using material-ui jss styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59178802/how-do-you-change-a-style-of-a-child-when-hovering-over-a-parent-using-material/59179458#59179458)
- [How to apply styles to a child class in JSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54184180/how-to-apply-styles-to-a-child-class-in-jss/54185534#54185534)
- [How to override style of nested Material UI component from the ancestors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60505479/how-to-override-style-of-nested-material-ui-component-from-the-ancestors/60510725#60510725)
- [What does the symbol '&$checked' mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59243783/what-does-the-symbol-checked-mean/59251768#59251768)

Comment: Ah yep that was always an option wanted to check if it was possible otherwise :)